# How to parse html from an external website

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, xml

I need to write a script that finds a URL on a web page, references that page, and returns information to the current page. I have to believe this is possible.

I've been researching this for hours to no avail.

Here's an example:

I'm on website A. There is a link on website A to website B. I want to locate the link to website B (already done), reference the HTML of website B, and return some of the HTML, likely using getElementByID(), or even XPath.

Does anyone know how to do this without breaking the current session?

Comment: if you're talking about code that's **on** page A, then you can't do it unless the server for website B wishes to allow it.

Comment: You can achieve this with an Ajax request but only if the server of B allows CORS